# Как вывести в столбик информацию из таблицы SQL

Tags: python, sql

У меня есть таблица. В ней есть список, а в нём 3 кортежа. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы каждый кортеж выводился таблицей. То есть вывод который я получаю:

> [('79354', 'Текст', 'Ещё текст', 'Tue Mar  8 21:52:42 2022'), ('91681', 'Текст1', 'Ещё текст1', 'Tue Mar  8 21:54:36 2022'), ('12149', 'Текст2 ', 'Ещё текст2', 'Tue Mar  8 21:55:05 2022')]

Но вот текст, который я хочу получить:

> [('79354', 'Текст', 'Ещё текст', 'Tue Mar  8 21:52:42 2022'),

> ('91681', 'Текст1', 'Ещё текст1', 'Tue Mar  8 21:54:36 2022'),

> ('12149', 'Текст2 ', 'Ещё текст2', 'Tue Mar  8 21:55:05 2022')]

Вот функция, вызывающая вывод таблицы:

```
def Total():
    global cur

    Total = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM taskActive").fetchall()
    print(Total)
    StartMenu()
```

Comment: `print(*Total, sep='\n')`

Comment: @Namerek Вы помогли. Оставьте ответ, чтобы я пометил его правильным. Ещё объясните пожалуйста, что делает знак * перед Total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` это так называемая распаковка итерируемого объекта
Тоесть при

```py
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Запись

```py
print(*a)
```

Будет эквивалентна записи

```py
print(a[0], a[1], a[2])
```

Кроме того:

```py
a = ['0', '1', '2']

b = [*map(int, a)]
# Будет эквивалентна записи
b = list(map(int, a))
```